# Regex literal works but Regx constructor doesn't

Tags: javascript, regex

I really need some help figuring out how to make the Regex constructor work. I need to use the constructor b/c I am passing in a variable.

The variable looks like this:
`/pages/one.html` or `/content/pages/x.html` or `/content/pages/x.html?cachebust=1&refresh=yesplease&one=1`

**Works**
`var regLit = /\/pages\/x\.html(\?success=true)?/g`

**Fails**
`var regCon = new RegExp("\/pages\/x\.html(\?success=true)?", "g")`

Here is my code. Please help SO!!!

```js
var closeMatch = function (list1, list2) {
    if (list1.length === list2.length) {
        return list1.every(function(item, index) {
            let re = item
                .replace(/[\/]/g, '\\/')
                .replace(/\./g, '\\.')
                .concat('(\?success=true)?');
            console.log(re, list2[index]);
            return new RegExp(re, 'g').test(list2[index]);
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

var arr1 = ['/pages/one.html', '/content/pages/x.html','/content/pages/x.html?success=true'];

var arr = ['/pages/one.html', '/content/pages/x.html','/content/pages/x.html?success=true&funnel=done&someother=blah'];

console.log(closeMatch(arr1, arr));
```

Comment: change  all \ -> \\ in the string version

Comment: That gives me an unexpected token error.

Comment: Just escape `?` with ``\\``. `.concat('(\\?success=true)?')`

Comment: OK, thanks for helping me out!